# How to handle this type of code in php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I handle this:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Uregister\accessd.php on line 33

Here's my code:

```
mysqli_select_db($database_user_informaion, $user_informaion);
$query_user_request = "SELECT * FROM user"; 
$user_request = mysqli_query($query_user_request, $user_informaion) or die(mysqli_error()); 
$row_user_request = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_request);
$totalRows_user_request = mysqli_num_rows($user_request);
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm getting same error now... here is my code

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: mysqli_select_db($database_user_informaion, $user_informaion);
$query_user_request = "SELECT * FROM `user`";
$user_request = mysqli_query($query_user_request, $user_informaion) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_user_request = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_request);
$totalRows_user_request = mysqli_num_rows($user_request);

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

**Example code**`

```
<?php
//Connect to database "one"
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "one") 

//Now change the database to "two"
mysqli_select_db($db, "two");

//Your code for whatever you want to do with the database
```